# How do I check if Kibana 4 is running on a linux machine?

Tags: kibana-4

I have configured a linux machine, I just wish to check if kibana 4 is running perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always use :

```
ps auwx | grep kibana
```

it'll list the kibana process

Care: it'll list also the command itself

Answer (score -1):

We can also use the command:
 `ps -ef | grep -irn kibana` 
This will list all the kibana processes running at the instance..

Comment: the first one worked for me, returning 1 result.  I couldn't get yours to return the same.